# Bmp to raw strange problem

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I have a strange problem in transform a stack of bmp images to raw file (unsigned char array) .This is the code :

```
for(int i=365;i<=385;i++)
    {
        sprintf(secondname,"C:\\tr\\tr_");
    sprintf(secondtemp,"_%04d.bmp",i);
    strcat(secondname,secondtemp);
    cvSaveImage( secondname,out);
    cvReleaseImage( &out );
    IplImage* img2 = cvLoadImage( secondname,0);
    memcpy(&im[xsize*ysize*(i-365)],img2->imageData,xsize*ysize);



    }
    outfile=fopen("C:\\Histo_Registration\\a.raw","wb");
    fwrite((unsigned char*)im,1,(xsize)*(ysize)*(zsize),outfile);
    fclose(outfile);
```

The problem is that when the images that i load is for example 512x512 the result raw is ok .When the images is 426x425 the result raw is strange is not for sure the correct one.Any idea?

Comment: There are extra bytes (padding) to align each row of the image to an address that is multiple of 4. Do you see the result image skewed?

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't work with bitmap line alignment. See IplImage::widthStep member. You cannot copy the whole image in one memcpy call, if widthStep is not equal to (pixel size in bytes * line width in pixels).

Windows bitmaps are 32-bit aligned, this is why 512x512 image is OK, and 426x425 is wrong. For example, if image width = 11, and every pixel is 1 byte length, actual line width (widthStep) will be 12 (4 bytes alignment).

Comment: Yes, and it's not just windows bitmaps that are 32-bit aligned. If you set a texture in OpenGL, it is also 32-bit aligned and many more examples. You should always be completely aware of the format of the image you are loading/saving.

Answer (score 1):

The length of each row in a BMP is a multiple of 4, if necessary the remaining bytes will be filled with 0. You need to take that into account.

See the [Wikipedia article about the BMP file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) for details.